# Floating validation in html

Tags: html, jquery, validation, floating

I have tried to [create the form](https://codepen.io/malavigne/pen/NAoqgX) **Floating** validation like [one of website](https://www.to-increase.com/ap-automation/talk-to-expert) it's working, but the right side image green/red color is not showing. For this I tried the [code](https://codepen.io/malavigne/pen/NAoqgX).

```
<html>
<head></head>


<body>

<div id="form_validation_c" class="form-wrap">
    <form action="#submit" method="post" class="validate go-bottom">

      <!-- First name -->
      <div class="column half">
          <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" required />
        <label for="firstname">
          Your First Name
        </label>
      </div>

      <!-- Last Name -->
      <div class="column half last">
        <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" required />
        <label for="lastname">
          Your Last Name
        </label>
      </div>
 
      <!-- Submit -->
      <div class="column submit">
        <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn_blue">Submit</button>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Can you please suggest us to show the green/red image on right side of the textbox based on validation?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with animation too .

> Provided an animation for valid `input` , you can restyle according to need . Here is a demo only

```css
input {
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0.25rem;
  min-width: 125px;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
  position: relative;
}

input:required:valid {
  background: url("https://assets.digitalocean.com/labs/icons/hand-thumbs-up.svg") no-repeat 95% 50% lightgreen;
  background-size: 25px;
  animation: bgFloat 0.5s linear
}

@keyframes bgFloat {
  0% {
    background-position: left center;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: right center;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>


<body>

  <div id="form_validation_c" class="form-wrap">
    <form action="#submit" method="post" class="validate go-bottom">

      <!-- First name -->
      <div class="column half">
        <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" required />
        <label for="firstname">
          Your First Name
        </label>
      </div>

      <!-- Last Name -->
      <div class="column half last">
        <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" required />
        <label for="lastname">
          Your Last Name
        </label>
      </div>

      <!-- Submit -->
      <div class="column submit">
        <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn_blue">Submit</button>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```